# Open Firefox in full screen on Mac OS

Tags: macos, firefox

I would like to configure Mozilla firefox browser to be opened in full screen mode, automaticly under mac OSX by default. Is there an option to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try System Preferences > General > Uncheck "Close windows when quitting an application".

This should preserver your window vs. full screen settings, so if you have firefox open on full screen and quit, when you reopen, it should open in full screen.

Comment: Didn't work for me. i still need to maximize the window when repoen Firefox